# How to plot Gradient graph with 3 axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, surface

I want to make a 2d surface plot which should looks something like this
[image]

```
for i in range(26):
    for u in range(11,102):
    line=linecache.getline("C:/Users/USER/Desktop/iteration/" + file_name[i],u)
    line=np.array(line.split())
    z.append(float(line[2]))
    vmr.append(float(line[3]))
x=np.linspace(4,6,num=3458)
y=np.array(z)
z=np.array(vmr)
xi, yi = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 100), np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), 
100)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
# Interpolate
zi = scipy.interpolate.griddata((x, y), z, (xi, yi), method='linear')

plt.imshow(zi, vmin=z.min(), vmax=z.max(), origin='lower',
       extent=[x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()])

plt.scatter(x, y, c=z)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

The Plot I got Using the above code is:

[image]

Should I try some other language/software other than python???
I'm new to this,any Help will be appreciated
Thank You

Comment: Thank You so much....it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the image plot has very different dimensions along both axes. Since `imshow` has per default an equal aspect you may get a result like the one you show in the question.

An easy solution for this is to loosen the constraint on the equal aspect ratio:

```
plt.imshow(...., aspect="auto")
```

Comment: I have one more problem What i get is a scatter plot,may be due to the command "plt.scatter()", can I replace it with something else so that i get a continuous gradient  plot as mentioned above   Thank You

Comment: Please remember that I don't have your data and thus do not have any chance of knowing what your plot looks like in comparisson to the desired plot.